# How can I share instagram username?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instagram

I am making on Xcode 6.1.1 and application and wanted to have a link that takes you to https://www.instagram.com/naturee/

I added this:

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=naturee"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

form

https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

But it takes me to Instagram application but not a username!

Does anyone know how??

Comment: Probably an Instagram bug and not something that can be answered here...

Comment: Do you have an alternative code?

Comment: No.. This looks right, but it's probably Instagram handling the URL wrong.

Comment: I don't .. understand :)

Comment: So it's probably Instagram bug, what would you do?

Comment: Not much you can do. https://help.instagram.com/381579045265733?ref=related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Support Universal Links in your application on iOS9.
There is more information on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Your code will work if you change ur NSURL by :
`NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.instagram.com/naturee/"];`

If you still want to use URL Scheme, there is something wrong with your actual one :`@"instagram://user?username=naturee"`. You can check it by opening safari on your device and past this url scheme. it won't open instagram's naturee's profile.

Comment: Let me get, I'll get back to you.

Comment: I guestion if you have time, how is the 'else' code is going to be? In case I don't have the Instagram App and it takes me to Safari

Comment: You don't have to put else code if in your case instagram is not installed on your device. iOs will automaticaly open Safari instead of the third tier application.

Comment: I removed the Instagram application from my iPhone, I tick on the button, it doesnt go there!

Comment: It doesn't open Safari ?

Comment: I put this  } else {
             //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
             UIApplication.sharedApplication().[openURL(NSURL(string: "http://instagram.com/naturee/")!)
    ]    but didn't work

Comment: NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.instagram.com/naturee/"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
    } will simply do all the job for you

Comment: It doesn't go to Safari if the Instagram app not on my iPhone!

Answer (score 1):

To understand Universal Links, it’s important to first understand deep links.

Deep links are nothing more than the ability to open up an application to a specific piece of app content. It’s akin to linking to a page other than a homepage on a website.

In order to deep link into an app, traditionally a developer had to register a protocol (i.e. instagram:// , twitter:// , facebook:// ) with the operating system when an app is installed. Subsequently, when an incoming request is received on the device to a registered protocol, the operating system launches the associated application, letting it handle the request (link).

This works well enough; however, if a developer has a website mirroring its app content it results in having to effectively manage, maintain, and synchronize two sets of URL schemes, one for the web and one for the app.

Universal Links try to solve this problem by enabling an app to handle incoming https://  requests (regular web requests).

On iOS 9, a user may navigate or click a link to a webpage and if that website is setup to handle Universal Links (and the app is installed on the device), the operating system will intercept the request (without opening Safari if not already open) and pass the request to the associated application.

Universal Links are an easy way to intelligently route web traffic to an application if available. It enables developers to make the app the default place to send web traffic on iOS, using the web as the backup destination if the app isn’t installed.

quoted from this [site](http://blog.tapstream.com/ios9-search-universal-links/)